# alternative to db query in blade view

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have the following tables

```
groups
- id
- title

categories
- id
- title
- parent_id
- group_id

threads 
- id 
- replies_count
- title
- category_id

replies
- id
- thread_id
```

- For each group, i display the title of the group
- For each category associated with a group, i display the title of the category, the total number of threads and replies associated with that category
- The **categories** table consists of **children** and **parent** categories. Therefore, when i display the title of  a **parent** category ( a category that has children ), i want to display next to the title, the total number of threads and replies that are associated with its children categories.

For the total number of threads for a parent category i have the following relationship and i load the count

```
protected $withCount = ['parentThreads']

  public function parentThreads()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            Thread::class,
            Category::class,
            'parent_id',
            'category_id'
        );
    }
```

For the total number of replies associated with a group i have the following code

```
public function getParentRepliesCount() {
    return $this->parentThreads()->sum('replies_count');
}
```

The problem is that in the blade view then i have to call this accessor which makes a query ( which is a bad practice, if i'm not mistaken )

```
<p> {{ $category->parent_replies_count }} </p>
```

My question is if there is a better alternative ?

Comment: can you add the code that loads the variable `$category` ?

Comment: laravel never added it to the core, but there are a couple packages that add things like `withSum` which is like `withCount` but for the purpose of summing a column .. you may want to look into something like that  [laravel PR for adding this functionality](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/32492)

Comment: in my case i want to do a withSum in a nested relationship. In his example, he loads the sum on a model like, Invoice::withSum(....), but in my case, i want to load the sum in a nested relationship. For example, i have Groups::with('parentCategories') and i need to load the sum on the parentCategories. I can't do Groups::with('parentCategories')->withSum(..) because i am referring to the groups here not to parentCategories